# AWS allow user to create policies that doesn't create other policies?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Is it possible to allow a user to create policies that doesn't contain any IAM Write actions, such as `iam:CreatePolicy` or `iam:AttachPolicyRole`?

The reason I'm asking is that the company I work at has a single person which can create policies & roles for security reasons. But this is quickly becoming a bottleneck, and we would like to transfer the responsibility of creating roles & policies to more people in a secure fashion. One way I can think is to limit the actions a policy can have, and the most sensitive actions are IAM actions, but I don't know if this is possible.

Comment: See [Prevent privilege escalation with AWS IAM permission boundaries](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LZdfxS2DnFw).

Comment: I understand that a permission boundary can disallow a user or a role to access resources, but couldn't a user create a policy/role to delegate a Lambda function to create an admin user, for example? The boundary wouldn't apply to the lambda, would it?

Comment: See the example in that same video at [t=507](https://youtu.be/LZdfxS2DnFw?t=507) where it shows how to prevent an IAM user from creating another IAM user or role without also configuring a pre-determined permission boundary on that user or role. A Lambda function execution with such an IAM role would then be constrained to that permission boundary.

Comment: YES! That's what I'm looking for. So, the permission boundary itself wouldn't allow me to create a Role without a permission boundary. Now I'm starting to understand. Thanks!

Comment: If you have the opportunity, test it briefly to confirm that it does what you need then I'd be happy to write up an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IAM has an important feature called [permissions boundaries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_boundaries.html):

> A permissions boundary is an advanced feature for using a managed policy to set the maximum permissions that an identity-based policy can grant to an IAM entity. An entity's permissions boundary allows it to perform only the actions that are allowed by both its identity-based policies and its permissions boundaries.

A permissions boundary is designed to restrict permissions on IAM principals (IAM users and IAM roles). It enforces a centrally-managed boundary that can’t be exceeded, even if broader permissions are granted by some other policy attached to the IAM principal.

Permissions boundaries can also be used to restrict what permissions that IAM principal can grant when creating new IAM principals.

Here's an example of an IAM statement that you could add to an IAM user's policies that would allow that user to create new IAM users and roles *but* restrict the created roles and users to a specified permissions boundary:

```
"Statement": [
  {
    "Sid": "AllowIAMCreate",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [ "iam:CreateUser", "iam:CreateRole" ],
    "Resource": "*"
  },
  {
    "Sid": "DenyIAMCreateWithoutBoundary",
    "Effect": "Deny",
    "Action": [ "iam:CreateUser", "iam:CreateRole" ],
    "Resource": [
      "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:user/*",
      "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/*"
    ],
    "Condition": {
      "StringNotEquals": {
        "iam":PermissionsBoundary": "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:policy/DevBoundary"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Here's a good introductory video: [Prevent privilege escalation with AWS IAM permission boundaries](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LZdfxS2DnFw)

Answer (score -1):

yes, you can create customer managed policies.by just a simply adding a permission in that policy.

Comment: If you're convinced that this approach answers the question, you should provide more detail. As it stands, it doesn't appear to be correct and the lack of detail doesn't allow readers to validate this approach.